# Why does my video play instantly in a UIWebView but takes forever to buffer and load with MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a large .m4v video file on an HTTP server. The video1.m4v file is 2GB in this example. As an example, this is the URL I want to hit:

```
http://www.myurl.com/movies/video1.m4v
```

When I load that URL in my `UIWebView` browser on my iPhone the file starts playing automatically and perfectly. I can skip ahead, go back, use Airplay, and everything works great and fast:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:movie.fileURL]];
```

When I load it up with this `MPMoviePlayerController` code it just hangs on `Loading` forever:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 270)];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
[moviePlayerController play];
```

**Why does it start buffering and playing so much quicker in my UIWebView (or mobile Safari if I load the URL from there) so much quicker than from MPMoviePlayerController?**

Comment: Because both players are different in many many aspects. Details are not disclosed by Apple and hence any answer could not rely on documented facts but only assumptions.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `MPMoviePlayerViewController` of `MPMoviePlayerController`

Check this link:
[Apple Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Try something like this

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpvc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];    

mpvc.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpvc];
```